# Name of effect on a company when the head changes

Tags: management, job-change, recruitment

I understand when a large company changes the head boss, it creates a ripple effect of changes through the entire company.

This is due to, the people directly under the new head boss will change how they work to meet different expectations compared to the previous boss.

This would have an effect on the expectations of those under them, and those under them, and so on.

What is this effect called? Or does it even have a name?

Comment: I think it's called "change."

Comment: @Blrfl I'd have called it "restructuring" - even if there are no firings/hirings.. The work and expectations are being restructured.

Comment: This question might be better suited for the [English SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/). They do lots of "What's the word for..." questions.

Comment: A recent management change at our company has often been described as a "Sh!t storm" however I believe restructuring may be a more politically correct way of referring to it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "name that thing" question. "Name that thing" are bad questions for the same reasons that "identify this obscure TV show, film or book by its characters or story" are bad questions: you can't Google them, they aren't practical in any way, they don't help anyone else, and allowing them opens the door for the asking of other types of marginal questions. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a language question not specific to the workplace.  Consider migrating to EL&U.

Answer (score 1):

Leadership turnover is a nifty phrase.  Probably the one I'd use to describe the event.

There's also relationship with authority (what the team has with the boss), and culture shift (what happens if the boss ends up being a big factor for change).

From a planning perspective, doing this with some plan in mind is "succession planning".

Answer (score 0):

It's just a matter of corporate leadership turnover. There isn't any one word or phrase for it, but you could call it change in company strategy or goals.

It's also worth noting that this doesn't always happen when someone new arrives in the C-suite; many times that person's predecessor will handpick them because they know that they will, for the most part, agree with and help manage the same corporate strategy as before.